# Python, writing things to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm in this sort of a situation. I have 2 lists and two ints, I need to put them all into a JSON file so that I can pass it to another Python program. I would like the final file/structure to be something along the lines of:

```
 File:{
        numbers : [1,2,3]
        strings : ["a", "b" , "c"]
        x : 0
        y : 0
    }
```

Is there a way to do this in an automated fashion without explicitly writing it all as one massive string? I assume it uses dumps, but I am not entirely sure how to use it properly and how it will incorporate the variables tag (i.e. numbers, string) or how to do add each line to a single JSON structure.

```
import json
n = [1, 2, 3]
s = ["a", "b" , "c"]
x = 0
y = 0
nums = json.dumps(n,)
strings = json.dumps(s)
print(nums)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put everything in a dict:

```
json.dumps({'numbers': n, 'strings': s, 'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Result:

```
>>> json.dumps({'numbers': n, 'strings': s, 'x': x, 'y': y})
'{"numbers": [1, 2, 3], "y": 0, "x": 0, "strings": ["a", "b", "c"]}'
```

Note that both JSON object and Python dicts do not have a specific ordering.

Comment: Shouldn't the keys for x and y be strings? I.e., `'x'` and `'y'`, not `x` and `y`.

Comment: will the internal order of numbers and strings be kept?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: Yes, because those are lists. Lists have order, both in Python and in JavaScript (JSON).

Comment: @user9876: Not a problem, I realized what had happened.

Comment: Great, Thanks. If you don't mind I have one more question. dumps, turns it into a json-able string, but it still needs to be loads-ed right?

Comment: @EasilyBaffled: You can use `json.dump()` to write the result straight to a file. `.loads()` turns a JSON string into a Python datastructure again, it is the mirror operation for `.dumps()`. Similarly, `.load()` takes a file to read from and return the Python structure from data stored in it.

Comment: Ah, thanks there was a little gap in my knowledge, now it all makes sense.